# Detect when list is scrollable?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I would like to add a background color to a list to make scrolling look better but I only want to it if the list is scrollable. How might I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple check and modify to meet your needs:

```
const dimensions = document.querySelector('selector').getBoundingClientRect();
if(dimensions.height > window.innerHeight) {
    // Element's height is bigger than window height, so it should be scrollable
    document.querySelector('selector').style('background', '#222');
}
```

You can test whether the height of the element is greater than the height of it's container.

Comment: Idk, you didn't post any code or context so I have no idea what your use case is and what your app setup is. This is as far as I can help with the info you provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The context is in the tag. :)